# R g++ error installing survey package

Tags: linux, ubuntu, r, g++

i get a **non-zero exit status** by installing the survey-package in R version 3.5.2 on ubuntu 18.04. the problem seems to be related to **g++** and the package **minqa**. in the output of the installation procedure i found the following g++ related lines:

g++  -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/winfried/rlibs/Rcpp/include"    -f

[...]

g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o minqa.so altm

[...]

g++: error: R: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

g++: error: version: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

g++: error: 3.5.2: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

g++: error: (2018-12-20): Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

Answer (score 0):

a cat statement in rprofile caused the problem. by silencing it the problem disappeared.

Comment: I had the same issue when installing other R packages (e.g., `Amelia`, `lme4`), and silencing the cat statement in my Rprofile file also solved the issue (took me hours of testing things before I came across this helpful answer!)